# Storefront theme : Add Categoy to recent products section

Tags: child-theme

I want to modify the Recent Products section Storefront theme to be able to include juste a specific category.
i tried that :

```
add_filter( 'storefront_recent_products_args', 'my_custom_storefront_category_args' );
function my_custom_storefront_category_args( $args ){
   $args = array(
    'limit' => 8,
    'columns' => 4,
    'category__in' => array ('35') 
    );
  return $args;
 }
```

but no success

Comment: I don't know Storefront, but I'd guess you want to modify the $args array passed in not completely overwrite it. What are those args used for? I'd guess not WP_Query since that doesn't have a columns value.

Comment: Yes I saw that. I think WP_Query () is not used. instead the [products] shortcode. I just want to add a Category coding. kept the same result, but for a product list of a category.

Comment: I found it , the question is resolved  : add_filter( 'storefront_recent_products_args', 'my_custom_storefront_category_args' );
function my_custom_storefront_category_args( $args ){
    $args = array(
        'limit' => 6,
        'columns' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'date',
  'order'   => 'desc',
  'category' => 'your-cat-slug',
  'cat_operator' => 'AND'
        );
    return $args;
}

Comment: Yes please mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it , the question is resolved :
Solution :

```
add_filter( 'storefront_recent_products_args','my_custom_storefront_category_args' );
function my_custom_storefront_category_args( $args ){ 
    $args = array( 
    'limit' => 6, 
    'columns' => 3, 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'desc', 
    'category' => 'your-cat-slug', 
    'cat_operator' => 'AND' 
    );

    return $args; 
}
```